# Duplicate max-age header

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, cache, proxypass

I'm using Apache 2.4.25 to expose a number of back-end services using proxy pass. Apache also sets the cache control headers based on mime type.  The current cache configuration looks like this:

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "now"
ExpiresByType text/html "now"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 120 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 120 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 120 minutes"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 60 minutes"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 60 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 60 minutes"
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 60 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 60 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-eot "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-svg "access plus 30 days"
```

However, one of the back-end services is also setting the cache-control max-age header.  This is causing the response header to contain two max-age settings.

[Duplicate max-agent values as seen in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyZnQ.png)

How does the browser react when presented with two max-age settings with different values?  Also, is it possible to check for an existing cache-control header before adding the default?

Comment: using `set` instead of `add` seems like the right thing to do, but I am still curious about how browsers interpret a duplicate setting. The RFC for Cache-control does not seem to specify any particular strategy: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.2 so maybe it's simply undefined. If that's the case, I wonder if all browsers actually handle it in different ways, or maybe there's an implicit standard they all adhere to?

Answer (score 3):

Use Header "set" instead of Header "add" if you don't want accidental duplicates due to backend sending the same header.

Comment: It seems like the ExpiresByType directive must be doing a header "add" instead of "set" then.  Would you recommend that I set the cache-control header another way then?

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest mod_expires docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

> When the Expires header is already part of the response generated by
>   the server [...] this module does not change or add an Expires or
>   Cache-Control header.

So one option is to get your backend to set an Expires header in addition to the Cache-Control header it's already setting. For instance, in PHP:

```
$seconds = 60;
header("Expires: ". gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $seconds). ' GMT');
header("Cache-Control: max-age=". $seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the Expires header is already part of the response generated by
>   the server [...] this module does not change or add an Expires or
>   Cache-Control header.

It isn't true, Apache still adds additional `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers.